# Change url in angular's factory

Tags: angularjs

How can I change url (just like clicking a href) from angular's factory?
I want to call "geo:" protocol in my mobile app (using ionicframework). I don't have $scope in factory

Answer (score 0):

it not good way to change URL from factory, it's better to bind model and change it

```
 <a ng-href="{{url}}">{{url}}</a>
```

and inside controller:

```
$scope.url = 'http://oyao.ru';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/STEVER/2YkeH/7/

Comment: I know but I have to do it from factory (there is service with google maps cordova plugin)

Comment: just do something like $scope.url = cordova.url;

Comment: I cannot - data are only markers on native map - they are not real DOM elements

Answer (score 0):

It may suit what you look for check it out here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/RLCB0lvLmrI